# R violin plot geom_violin avoid vertical lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting violin plots using geom_violin from the ggplot2 package it always generates vertical lines spanning the entire range of the y-axis. 
I updated R and R studio on both Macbook and Windows system without success. 
What do I need to change?

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_violin(trim=F)
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify: I am referring to the VERTICAL lines that are part of the violin plots themselves. Not the horizontal lines that are part of the background.

Comment: Those vertical lines go away if you set `trim=TRUE`, is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @r2evans if trim=TRUE the plots are trimmed and the vertical lines go away, yes. However, I expect the vertical lines to also go away when trim=FALSE. In the documentation the lines don't span the entirety of the y-axis range.

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_violin.html): `If TRUE (default), trim the tails of the violins to the range of the data. If FALSE, don't trim the tails.` The "range of the data" (quantified with `by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, range)` seems fairly depicted. Note that the default of `density` is to extend by [*"`cut * bw` outside of `range(x)`"*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/density.html), so ggplot's depiction might be slightly different with `trim=TRUE` than `plot(density(x))`.

Comment: As a small plug, if you're able to use base graphics, I have a small [`violinplot`](https://github.com/r2evans/violinplot) package that does not have these tails (nor the option to enable them, apparently). I can't say it's perfect, and the documentation/interface could use some improvement, but it works in a pinch, in which case your command could be `violinplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)`.

Comment: This behavior has change over time and there is currently some discussion as to what is the 'right' behavior, see [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1700), [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1783) and [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1793). I suspect this will change on a new release. You can probably get the old results by downgrading to an earlier version of `ggplot`, using `devtools::install_version('ggplot2', '1.0.1')`.

Comment: Another option is to make a local version of the way you want `geom_violin()` to work and keep it with your project. That way you're not going to feel the pain of potential behavior changes (unless Hadley changes the object model again, which is unlikely).

Comment: Thank you for everybody's input. Changing to a previous version fixed the problem!